# Engine Turns Over Gets to 500rpm, Shakes, Then Loses Power After Spark Plug & Wire Change

Tags: starting, sparkplugs, rough-idle, shaking

I drive a 1994 TOYT Camry LE 2.2L Coupe.

A couple days ago while I was driving, I stopped at a stop light and my engine block started shaking the whole care at low speeds and idle.

I replaced the spark plugs (one seemed especially bad) and the spark plug wires, and now when I turn it on, it barely comes on, gets to 500rpm, shakes, then loses power. If I give it gas, it will last a little longer at 500rpm, shaking a lot, and then dies when I let go of the gas.

What might I have messed up when replacing the spark plugs that it does this? I double checked that everything was well connected. And does it sound like an "only spark plug" problem, or is there something else at work here?

Comment: Did you set the spark plug gaps when you put them in and did you follow manufacturer recommendations? It's also possible the timing is out. If the plugs are set correctly and everything is wired up OK, I'd have the points and distributor cap replaced (relatively cheap) and have a timing test done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go back and look at the firing order of the spark plug wires you installed. If you get two out of place on a four cylinder engine, you now only have two good firing cylinders, and depending on which two got switched, one of them may even be firing the cylinder at opposition to the rest, not allowing the engine to get anywhere close to operating speeds.

Here is the firing order diagram to help you:

[image]

Comment: That was the correct answer and I fixed it, but it seems as there is another problem that wasn't there before. 

Now when I start it, it turns over well for a second, then makes a loud clashing sound (or pop sound), and suddenly stops. Any ideas?

Comment: I feel stupid, because I just wrote that there was another problem, but I had actually still accidentally switched two of the wires. I think there isn't enough juice to rollover, so I'm charging the batter, and I'll know more once that is finished.

Comment: @lawdawg - All I can say is, triple check this bad boy to ensure the firing order is correct. It's way too easy to get them mixed up. It's a lot easier these days with coil over/coil on ignition systems, that's for sure!

Comment: So I had double-checked the firing order and somehow was still wrong. Dont' know how I got it wrong so many times in a row haha

Comment: @lawdawg ... It happens to the best of us! Sounds like you got it right though.